# Size dropdown not coming in Magento 2 CE

Tags: magento2

I am facing an issue in Magento 2 CE. I have created configurable products with their respective simple products with size options. But I am unable to see the dropdowns of size on product detail page.

Comment: So, what did u see on product page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too. As per my experience, **the problem occurs if you change attribute options after assigning to products**.

To fix the issue, you need to:

- First, log into the admin panel and go to **Stores > Attributes > Product**.
- Find **size** attribute and **delete all options**.
- **Recreate all options** and save attribute.
- Now you need to **re-assign options to all simple products**. You can do this manually from admin panel or by using the CSV import method.
- After that refresh the cache.

**Note:** In some cases, you may need to re-associate simple products to configurable products.

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `Visible on Product View Page on Front-end` property is set to **Yes** in backend for that **size** attribute. Also try after reindexing and cache clean.